# how we can enforce encryption at REST over RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am facing problem with Rabbitmq.

i just want to know that how we can enforce encryption at REST over RabbitMQ??

please provide me any proper solution so that i could move forward.

Regards
Vikas

Comment: what did you tried till now. Put the code in your question.

Comment: i just enabled ssl on RabbitMQ.

now i want to know

 how we can enforce encryption at REST over RabbitMQ ?

Comment: I'm curious, how REST relates to RabbitMQ here?

Comment: ok i got my answer ....    zaq178miami  you are right :)

Comment: @pinepain I guess he means data at 'rest', as opposed to 'in transit'. Bad choice of upper-casing :)